# GitLab CE post-commit custom hook not working

Tags: git, gitlab, hook

I use GitLab Community Edition 8.2 and want to add post-commit hook.

I created file path_to_project.git/custom_hooks/post-commit with rights

```
$ ls -l1 custom_hooks/post-commit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 git git 45 Dec 14 21:31 custom_hooks/post-commit
```

and content

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test custom" > /tmp/hook
```

as described here: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html

But it not work (check by commiting via web interface). I tried also 'normal' git hook placement (project.git/hooks/post-commit), but it not work also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`post-commit` is a **client-side** hook and you can not implement it on server.

According to Gitlab documentation: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html, you can implement a **server-side** custom hook (`pre-receive`, `post-receive`, `and update`) at the server.

> Examples of server-side git hooks include pre-receive, post-receive,
>   and update. See [Git SCM Server-Side Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) for more information about
>   each hook type.

If you want to customize a client-side hook, you will need to change the original hook code or put your custom script at client under `.git/hooks`. Read more here: [What are Git hooks?](http://githooks.com/)

And here is all about custom hooks: [Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)

Comment: Yes, I tried to put that hook to .git/hooks (where is post-receive, pre-receive and update hooks located). Nothing changed.

Comment: Well, please read again the differences between client-side and server-side hooks. The documentation is about server-side hooks. Those are located at server under `... gitlab-shell/hooks`. Check this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1742

Comment: Ohhh. I'm stupid. :( Sorry for inattentive read. All working as expected with post-receive hook, post-commit isn't work on server side, you're right.

Comment: Glad that you could sort it out :)